# Binary on a diet

Tags: computer-puzzle, cipher, history

How can you make binary data less filling?

Remove the 1s, of course.

```
 OO O OO      O OO OOOO
  OO  OO O      O OOO O
  OOOOO       OOO  O O
  OOO OO       OO OO  O
               OOO OO
  OOO OOOO
 OOO  O  O     O   O  O
 OOOO O OO     O O O OO
              OO   O OO
 OOOO O OO    OO  OO  O
  OO  OO O    OO  OO  O
  OOO O O
 OOOO OOO     OOO  O O
  OO  OO O    OOOOOO  O
 OOO  OO       OOO OO
               OO  OO O
  OO OO  O    OOOO O OO
 OOO OOOO       O OOOO
```

Some who remember the 1960s were more into computers than counterculture.
They may remember a time when stored text was less filling than now.
One reason for that relative efficiency
is given in the two-column mystery sentence above,
encoded authentically for those days.

What was that reason?

What is this encoding?

Comment: Looks like a punch card, maybe?

Comment: Yah. Punchcard with a parity bit. Not at home tho or I'd go for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> Text was served in 7-bit ASCII bytes.

The encoding is

> ASCII on a punch tape with sprocket holes after the 5th bit. The first bit is a parity bit.
>  
>  Each `O` in the puzzle is a hole that is interpreted as `1` or `#` here:
>
> ```
> Binary        Dec  ASCII     Binary        Dec  ASCII
> (1)1010#100    84    T       (1)0110#111    55    7
> (0)1100#101   101    e       (0)0101#101    45    -
> (0)1111#000   120    x       (1)1100#010    98    b
> (0)1110#100   116    t       (0)1101#001   105    i
>                              (0)1110#100   116    t
> (0)1110#111   119    w
> (1)1100#001    97    a       (0)1000#001    65    A
> (1)1110#011   115    s       (0)1010#011    83    S
>                              (1)1000#011    67    C
> (1)1110#011   115    s       (1)1001#001    73    I
> (0)1100#101   101    e       (1)1001#001    73    I
> (0)1110#010   114    r
> (1)1110#110   118    v       (1)1100#010    98    b
> (0)1100#101   101    e       (1)1111#001   121    y
> (1)1100#100   100    d       (0)1110#100   116    t
>                              (0)1100#101   101    e
> (0)1101#001   105    i       (1)1110#011   115    s
> (1)1101#110   110    n       (0)0101#110    46    .
> ```
>
> (To be complete, each space between words would be `"O O  O   "` in the puzzle and `"(1)0100#000  32"` here.)
>  
>  See also: [Newcastle University – Virtual Museum – 8 Hole Paper Tape](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/roger.broughton/museum/iomedia/pt1.htm)
>  
>  [image]

Comment: Cool! I didn't notice the sprocket holes, so I thought it was some 8-bit encoding with a 9th parity bit. Do you know if this tape is punched according to an actual punch card standard?

Comment: It is a 8 hole punched TAPE. Punch cards need no sprocket holes. See https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/roger.broughton/museum/iomedia/pt1.htm

Comment: A little formal nitpicking though: space characters should still have sprocket holes. This tape might get stuck like this...